# Soft keyboard hides TextFormField inside the InteractiveViewer

Tags: flutter, android-softkeyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

I am having a text form field at the bottom of the screen. I wrap this text form field inside a Interactive Viewer. When the text form field is focused, the soft keyboard rises and hides the text form field.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            top: 700,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: TextFormField(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true`. How to move the text form field to the top of the soft keyboard so that it stays visisble? And I don't want to wrap the InteractiveViewer in a `SingleChildScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try not specifying the top: 700.  Just have bottom: 0 if you want the TextFormField pinned to the bottom of the available space.

Comment: I don't want the TextFormField to be pinned to the bottom. In my application, the TextFormField are spread across the screen which will be positioned by the `Positioned` Widget. The TextFormField which are positioned to the bottom of the screen are hidden by the keyboard.

Comment: If you specify a top of 700, that will end up getting hidden.  You need to come up with a layout that will adjust to different size containers.  When the keyboard is displayed, your InteractiveViewer will be contained in a smaller space.